# Interstitial ads on SpriteKit

Tags: objective-c

I have a little problem with showing interstitial ads with my app using Sprite Kit.
As we all know interstitial ads are shown each time we go from an UIviewController to another one(something like a segue), so it needs at least to UIviewController(s). But in my case, all I have is one UIviewController. Can you help showing such ads on my app.
Also, I want to know if there is a way to manage those ads from SKScene.m.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your gonna wanna look up NSNotificationCenter. Figure out how to use it and you'll be good to go. GL